# How to save list in bulk in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am trying to save a list of items is there a way to save it in bulk rather than using the loop.

```
 $id = $organization->id;
        $memberDetails = session()->get('memberDetails');
        foreach ($memberDetails as list($type, $name, $number, $email)) {
            $member = new Member;
            $member->org_id = $id;
            $member->type = $type;
            $member->name = $name;
            $member->wnumber =$number;
            $member->email= $email;
            $member->save();
        }
```

Comment: You can use the loop to create the array, and then use the [insert](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#inserts) method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should but the members values you want to insert in an array then insert them:

```
 $arrayValues=[];
        foreach ($memberDetails as list($type, $name, $number, $email)) {
            $rowArray=[];
            $rowArray['org_id']=$id;
            $rowArray['type']=$type;
            $rowArray['name']=$name;
            $rowArray['wnumber ']=$number;
            $rowArray['email']=$email;
            $arrayValues[]=$rowArray;
        }

Member::insert($arrayValues);
```